# Fatal error: Class 'Htmlfilter' not found in

Tags: opencart

I have some error in Open Cart POS System Module install in My Open Cart Website.

My Open Cart Version is : `3.0.3.2`

Error is :

> Fatal error: Class 'Htmlfilter' not found in
>   /home/www/pos.waaneizadigitalmarket.com/admin/controller/extension/module/wkpos.php
>   on line 291

Line 291 in code is following :

```
    $this->registry->set ('Htmlfilter', new Htmlfilter($this->registry));
    $this->request->post['wkpos_logcontent1'] = htmlentities($this->Htmlfilter->HTMLFilter(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['wkpos_logcontent1']),'',true));
```

What is Wrong in Code and How can I fix That .

Answer (score 0):

As its a custom module, this is purely a guess. However, I'd say its that you've not included the file that contains the `Htmlfilter` class. Be sure that its added using an `include` or `require` linking to the class file

Answer (score 0):

Check System->Library for A File Like Htmlfilter or Search in The Project. As the Error says, the Htmlfilter class is not available.